# Missing commits in GitHub using Code Sandbox

Tags: github, repository, commit

I want to check if anyone has encountered this problem. I had created a branch repository on GitHub and was working on it using Code Sandbox app. I made a few updates, tested the code and all was working fine.

A month later, I came to continue working on it, but had discovered all the work that I had committed during that period was missing, and that the branch was back to how when I first installed it.

I checked the commit history, and none of the commits I had made were listed.

So it looks like I'm unable to access any of the code, files that I had created or worked on and retrieve my code, and will have to start again.

I just can't figure out what's happened to all of my work, and if there is a way to retrieve it? I was hoping to use GitHub log to see when the updates were done, but nothing is logged during that period, which is what's concerning me the most. I can't understand how all the commits are missing from the logs.

I had only created one branch, and I'm 100% certain that was the branch I was working on. It is even listed as the most recent project under Code Sandbox.

If anyone has had a similar problem, or could explain what might have happened, I would greatly appreciated any advice. Thanks